# Case SQL If there is no record between dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm new to SQL and am struggling with a case. 
I would like to make the case where if an account (account_ID) doesn't have a record (ON billing_id) between current_date-302 and current_date-62 THEN MARK WITH A "1"

Query below:

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
    billing_date_local_time
    ,account_id
    ,contract_owner_name
    ,date_first_feature_partner
    ,deal_starts_at
    ,contract_id
    ,new_partner_type
    ,sum(voucher_sold) AS Vouchers
    ,sum(gross_bookings_local) AS GB
    ,sum(gross_revenue_local) AS GR
    ,is_G2
    ,Case when billing_date_local_time between current_date-302 and current_date-62 = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO'  End
FROM EMEA_ANALYTICS.eu_deal_flat 
WHERE 
      country_id = 206 
  and billing_date_local_time between current_date-400 
  and current_date-2

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11
```

Comment: remove the =0 after current_date-62. That solves your problem.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *mark it with a "1"*?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a correlated subquery; something like this:

```
select 
a.billing_date_local_time
,a.account_id
,...
, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMEA_ANALYTICS.eu_deal_flat b WHERE a.account_id = b.account_id AND b.billing_date_local_time between current_date-302 and current_date-62 ) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
from 
FROM EMEA_ANALYTICS.eu_deal_flat a
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks - but when i update the query as suggested I get an error select-failed 3771 illegal expression in when clause of case expression - any ideas?

Comment: Im Using Teradata if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an aggregate function like this:

```
min(case when billing_date_local_time 
              between current_date-302 and current_date-62
         then 0
         else 1
    end)
```